# Can't put size of calendar to occupy all the width using fullcalendar

Tags: html, jquery, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

[This is how the calendar appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltDYR.png)

This is my code

```
<div id='calendar' ></div>

<script>

    $(function () {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            aspectRatio: 1,
            initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            dayClick: function () {
                alert('a day has been clicked!');
            },
            events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json'
        });

    });

</script>


#calendar {
max-width: 900px;
margin: 40px auto;
padding: 0 10px;}
```

I'm using Flask with jquery

What do I need to do? I didn't found anyone else with this problem

Comment: The code you've shown us does not, by itself, reproduce the issue from your screenshot - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/wvJLwOZ?editors=0110 . I would guess you have some other CSS in your page which is interfering with fullCalendar.

Comment: My god you were right, don't even know why that didn't come to my head, thank you very much!